# Bash scripting passing with in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, flags

I have main.sh and inside it calls sub.sh. However, I need to pass information to sub.sh. Can it be done like this:

```
wget centos_64bit_novz.sh 
sh centos_64bit_novz.sh --LEVEL=$LEVELSEC --SERVVRT=novz
```

Comment: assuming your script understands and knows how to parse the options --LEVEL and --SERVVRT ... sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `wget -O-`, you put content into `stdout`.
And with `bash -s`, you can use arguments.

```
wget centos_64bit_novz.sh -O- | bash -s --LEVEL=$LEVELSEC --SERVVRT=novz
```